# Error al tratar de leer un array de bytes. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'responseData',

Tags: c#, json, nodejs, api

Tengo una API en NodeJS que devuelve un esquema como este:

```
let productoSchema = new Schema({
    codigo: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, '{PATH} requerido'],
        unique: true
    },
    descripcion: {
        type: String
    },
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, '{PATH} requerido'],
    },
    precioCosto: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, '{PATH} requerido'],
    },
    precioVenta: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, '{PATH} requerido'],
    },
    estado: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    categoria: {
        required: [true, '{PATH} requerido'],
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Categoria'
    },
    marca: {
        required: [true, '{PATH} requerido'],
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Marca'
    },
    imagenByteArray: {
        type: [Buffer]
    }
};
```

Si ven la última propiedad, ahí guardo un array de bytes.

La API tiene un método que devuelve un producto, probando con Postman me devuelve bien por ejemplo:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "entidadResultante": {
        "imagenByteArray": [
            {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    47,
                    57,
                    ... ACA SIGUE EL ARRAY PERO LO BORRO PARA QE VEAN
                ]
            }
        ],
        "_id": "6019dc5ba038e84d1421a3f2",
        "codigo": "AAAAAA",
        "descripcion": "aaaaaaaaaaa",
        "nombre": "aaaaaa",
        "precioCosto": 123,
        "precioVenta": 3132213,
        "categoria": {
            "_id": "5fac0163ac7fe522acc202c3",
            "nombre": "Aperitivos"
        },
        "marca": {
            "_id": "6011e7283408972b34fd04a7",
            "nombre": "ASD"
        }
    }
}
```

En Postman puedo ver el resultado, pero al tratar de convertirlo en C# con JSON me devuelve la siguiente excepcion:

> InnerException = {"Unexpected token when reading bytes: StartObject.
> Path 'entidadResultante.imagenByteArray[0]', line 1, position 52."}

El modelo que tengo en C# es el siguente:

```
public class Producto
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public decimal precioCosto { get; set; }
    public decimal precioVenta { get; set; }
    public bool estado { get; set; }
    public int cantidad { get; set; }
    public Categoria categoria { get; set; }
    public Marca marca { get; set; }
    public byte[] imagenByteArray{ get; set; }
}
```

Y el código para pegarle a la API es este:

```
public Respuesta<Producto> GetProductoById(string idProducto)
        {
            urlParameters = "?cantidad=100";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{URL}/producto/{idProducto}");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var respuesta = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Respuesta<Producto>>().Result;
                client.Dispose();
                return respuesta;
            }
            else
            {
                client.Dispose();
                return new Respuesta<Producto>();
            }
        }
```

Da error en la linea `var respuesta = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Respuesta<Producto>>().Result;`

Trate de pasar el JSON por [https://json2csharp.com/][1] y me puso que deje el modelo de Producto de C# de esta forma:

```
public class Producto
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public decimal precioCosto { get; set; }
    public decimal precioVenta { get; set; }
    public bool estado { get; set; }
    public int cantidad { get; set; }
    public Categoria categoria { get; set; }
    public Marca marca { get; set; }
    public ImagenByteArray imagenByteArray { get; set; }
}

public class ImagenByteArray
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<int> data { get; set; }
}
```

Pero ahí me devuelve esta excepcion:

> InnerException = {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g.
> [1,2,3]) into type 'Contratos.ImagenByteArray' because the type
> requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize
> correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON
> object (e.g....

Alguna idea de que pasa? Gracias por tomarse su tiempo en leer.
[1]: https://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución, en el contrato de Producto de C# hice estos cambios:

```
public class Producto
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public decimal precioCosto { get; set; }
    public decimal precioVenta { get; set; }
    public bool estado { get; set; }
    public int cantidad { get; set; }
    public Categoria categoria { get; set; }
    public Marca marca { get; set; }
    //public byte[] imagenByteArray{ get; set; }
    public ImagenByteArray[] imagenByteArray { get; set; }
}

public class ImagenByteArray
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public byte[] data { get; set; }
}
```

Viendo mejor como era la respuesta pude ver el problema.